# Cannot get value from map in k8s secret using jsonpath

Tags: json, kubernetes

I am trying to read a specific value from a secret using kubectl 1.18.8.

I can get the following just fine:

```
$ kubectl get secret my-secret -o jsonpath='{.data}'
map[.dockercfg:ey.....==]
```

But when I do:

```
$ kubectl get secret my-secret -o jsonpath='{.data\.dockercfg}'
$
```

or:

```
$ kubectl get secret my-secret -o jsonpath='{.data.dockercfg}'
$
```

I just get nothing.

Why can't I read the specify value associated with the key: `dockercfg`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** Did not notice that you use a key named `.dockercfg`.

You miss one dot before the escaped dot. This should work:

```
kubectl get secret my-secret -o jsonpath='{.data.\.dockercfg}'
```